# Array out of bounds>

Tags: java

I need to create a program that calculates the change that you would recieve, but it says:

**Exception in thread "main"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 
9 out of bounds for length 5
    at Main.main(Main.java:34)**

I'm fairly new at using arrays in Java so any pointers would be helpful

```
import java.math.*;

public class Main {

    static int changeTotal, penny, nickel, dime, quarter, dollarBill,  fiveBill, tenBill, twentyBill, fiftyBill, hundredBill;
    static double payed, price;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter cost of item");
        price = myScan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter money given");
        payed = myScan.nextDouble();

        int priceInt = (int) (price * 100);
        int payedInt = (int) (payed * 100);

        penny = 1;
        nickel = 5;
        dime = 10;
        quarter = 25;
        dollarBill = 100;

        int[] currencyArray = {penny, nickel, dime, quarter, dollarBill};
        int[] changeCount = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; 
        if(payed > price) {
        changeTotal = payedInt - priceInt;
        }

        for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
          int remainder = (changeTotal % currencyArray[i]);
            if(remainder < changeTotal) { 
                changeCount[i] = (changeTotal - remainder) / currencyArray[i]; 
            changeTotal = remainder;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(payed - price);
        System.out.println("Ones: " + changeCount[4]);
        System.out.println("Quarters: " + changeCount[3]);
        System.out.println("Dimes: " + changeCount[2]);
        System.out.println("Nickels: " + changeCount[1]);
        System.out.println("Pennies: " + changeCount[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in your `for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)`. The `currencyArray` and `changeCount ` have only 5 elements and you try to iterate 9 elements. Short fix change the limit of your `for` to `i = 4`

Answer (score 2):

To add on to previous answers, I would suggest using a reference to the array's length instead of hard wiring the value. It can be a decent practice to get into with cases like this where you're using a for loop to iterate through an array since then if the array changes in the future for whatever reason you don't have to track down the hard coded value to adjust it as well. Something like `for(int i = currencyArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)` for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] currencyArray = {penny, nickel, dime, quarter, dollarBill};
```

This assigns 5 elements in your array and now the size of your array is 5 which means you can access index 0 to 4.

```
for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
          int remainder = (changeTotal % currencyArray[i]);
```

In this lines, you are trying to index 9 which is not allocated to  the array. Hence it is Array out of bound index.

Answer (score 0):

the length of `currencyArray` is 5 and in your code, you try to access the element of index 9 which is doesn't exists, that why you getting this exception.

edit your loop by starting from the last index

```
for(int i = currencyArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  int remainder = (changeTotal % currencyArray[i]);
  if(remainder < changeTotal) { 
      changeCount[i] = (changeTotal - remainder) / currencyArray[i]; 
      changeTotal = remainder;
  }
}
```

`currencyArray.length` returns the length of the array, since the string index is 0 then you need to subtract one from the length to start from the last index